# Using interfaces. How can I verify my Java interface?

Tags: java, interface

I am trying to understand Java interfaces like the millions of others around the world.  How do I test that I'm really using my interface?  If I remove the "implements" in my TestBubbles class I still get the same results.  I can change either method definition and get a compilation failure but how do I test the data I'm passing?

```
public interface Bubbles {
   public void addAir(String bubbleType, float bubbleOne, float bubbleTwo );
}
```

---

```
public class TestBubbles implements Bubbles {

    public static void main(String [] args){
      String type = "wiggly";
      float sizeOne = 42.01f;
      float sizeTwo = 80.10f;

      TestBubbles tb = new TestBubbles();
      tb.addAir(type, sizeOne, sizeTwo);

}


   public void addAir(String rType, float fOne, float fTwo ){
       System.out.println(rType + " " + fOne + " " + fTwo);

   }

}
```

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, you'd get an error saying you haven't implemented `addAir()` if the method signature didn't match...not sure if that helps! You could verify you're using the interface with `if (tb instanceof Bubbles)`, but i'm not sure that's what you're asking.

Comment: An interface doesn't actually guarantee anything other than a method with the given type signature exists. "Verifying the interface" could be as simple as you can compile your code and assign it to a variable with the type of your interface.

Comment: @HoundDog: I'm using vim and tmux.  No IDE until I get the basics.

Comment: @Charlie:  So I guess it's just like what I did, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test that, and you should code that by defining your variables with the type of the interface instead the type of your class.
Look at your line:

```
TestBubbles tb = new TestBubbles();
tb.addAir(type, sizeOne, sizeTwo);
```

When programming to interfaces that should be coded as follows:

```
Bubbles tb = new TestBubbles();
tb.addAir(type, sizeOne, sizeTwo);
```

That way you later could exchange TestBubbles with SuperTrooperTestBubbles which implements the same Interface by only changing one line of code, and the rest will work:

```
Bubbles tb = new SuperTrooperTestBubbles();
tb.addAir(type, sizeOne, sizeTwo);
```

Where

```
public class SuperTrooperTestBubbles implements Bubbles { ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should refer to the object using the variable of the interface type.

e.g.

```
Bubbles tb = new TestBubbles(); //now it will not compile if you remove implements
```

not as follows (otherwise there would be no point in creating the interface)

```
TestBubbles tb = new TestBubbles();
```

Comment: the other thing you should do is to add @Override annotation to any method that is implementing an interface method (as of java 6 anyway, in java 5, it is only for overridden methods).  This will inform the compiler that the method in question must either override a superclass method or implement an interface method (not sure why they are not separate annotations) or an error will be generated.

Comment: @Steven had already suggested that so I left it out. It should have created a separated annotation for implementation, after all we are not overriding anything while implementing. Thanks for the Java version, I wasn't sure of the version 6.

Answer (score 0):

If an interface specifies any constraints on the input variables, it's up to the concrete implementation to check them.  There is no magic solution.

That said, you can mark methods as `@Override` which makes it a compiler error if it *doesn't* override another method, which is useful for this situation.  I always do this.